# how to get all markers on google-maps-v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to get all the markers on Google Maps?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to do. Also if you have any code please post it so that we can help you with come up with a solution, rather than just giving you code.

Comment: [a very useful link on this topic](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove)

Comment: @zjm1126... perhaps you can answer Voltin's question in comment sometime within the next three years? And let us know if there is a best answer among the posted ones. If none.. please proved a self-answer.. I assume after gained 14k rep you can answer your own question by now ;-P

Answer (score 91):

If you mean "how can I get a reference to all markers on a given map" - then I think the answer is "Sorry, you have to do it yourself". I don't think there is any handy "maps.getMarkers()" type function: you have to keep your own references as the points are created:

```
var allMarkers = [];
....
// Create some markers
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...});
    allMarkers.push(marker);
}
...
```

Then you can loop over the `allMarkers` array to and do whatever you need to do.

Comment: just want to verify if this still relevant for today or there a support the retrieve the markers from the map now?

Comment: still relevant, seems like theres no other way unless you store the markers in a specific array defined by yourself

Comment: Worked wonderfully- needed to remove existing markers and manipulating the newly created array did the trick. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The one way found is to use the [geoXML3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) library  which is suitable for usage along with KML processor  Version 3 of the Google Maps JavaScript API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have multiple markers that you wish to display on a google map.

The solution is two parts, one to create and populate an array containing all the details of the markers, then a second to loop through all entries in the array to create each marker.

Not know what environment you're using, it's a little difficult to provide specific help.

My best advice is to take a look at this article & accepted answer to understand the principals of creating a map with multiple markers:
[Display multiple markers on a map with their own info windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870670/multiple-infowindows-tearing-my-hair-out)

Answer (score -2):

If you are using JQuery Google map plug-in then below code will work for you -

`var markers = $('#map_canvas').gmap('get','markers');`

Comment: $(...).gmap is not a function

Answer (score -3):

For an specific cluster use:
getMarkers()    Gets the array of markers in the clusterer.

For all the markers in the map use:
getTotalMarkers()   Gets the array of markers in the clusterer.

Answer (score -5):

Google Maps API v3:

I initialized Google Map and added markers to it. Later, I wanted to retrieve all markers and did it simply by accessing the map property "markers".

```
var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: 40.730610,
    lng: -73.935242,
});

var myMarkers = map.markers;
```

You can loop over it and access all Marker methods listed at [Google Maps Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker).