# Custom google maps markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

I am trying to make custom Google maps. The idea is to make a map with 3 different markers for example: forest, river, lake.

I know how to add these custom markers. I do this with this [tutorial](http://stiern.com/tutorials/adding-custom-google-maps-to-your-website/), but I need to sort markers. For example when I press link "forest" in map will show only "forest" markers. Please help with this question, I try search in Google example, but found nothing that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply keep a list / array of all markers for a similar scenario. Actually I have written a Javascript meta object for this purpose, so I can search for all markers of a particular type etc.

A very simple solution is to keep three lists, one for each type. So you can iterate over all lists and hide/display the markers as appropriate.

Edit 1:

1. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6662514/356726 to get a first impression.
2. Here a [tutorial](http://marcgrabanski.com/article/jquery-google-maps-tutorial-basics/) using the concept in combination with jQuery.

Comment: Ok I will try this idea with array, now i studying Google Maps JavaScript API v3, I'm not good in JS, better solution for my will be jQuery but it's probably is inposible ;D

Comment: If you are new to Js use an array first, then use setVisible on the markers as appropriate. Good luck ;-) see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6662514/356726