# Google Maps Api - newbie

Tags: google-maps

I am starting to work on a Google Maps project, but I am totally new to Google Maps Api, as well as my JavaScript skills are quite small, my background is Java. I have started reading throught the docs and tutorials, but some basic questions stay unanswered, so I hope to get some help from you.

1. Does Google Maps api provide a way for user access control? Lets say, I have a map where my registered users(Joomla site) can add placemarks, how do I tell Google Maps if this user is allowed to work on the map? Or do I have to take care of that by myself without the Maps API?
2. What would be the right approach to create the following functionality: I want to let a user add a placemark to an empty map. Then I will check if the point added is ok for public publishing. If it's ok, then I want to transfer that placemark to the public map.
3. Is there some Maps API function to read out the placemarks on a specific map?

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Regarding the user access control, it seems that I have mixed two things. When you use Google Maps on Google website, and you create your map with markers, you can specify other users who are allowed to add and edit markers on that map. However, Google Maps api obviously does not save a server side copy of the map you are working on. So everything happens at your site. If you add markers, then you have to keep track of them by yourself, so also user access control is your own problem.
   However, I wonder, what would happen when I would create my own map on the Google Maps website with my own markers, and then I would display this map on my site. What would be then the way to read out the markers, lets say for a list of markers.
2. It seems that the right way is to implement it all yourself. Let user set marker, save the marker in database. Review the marker and if accepted mark it and display it on the public map when populating the map with your markers.
3. Ok, so I've been reading around and I found out, that obviously Google Maps does not provide a function to read out all markers on a map: [how to get all markers on google-maps-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577417/how-to-get-all-markers-on-google-maps-v3)