# how to retrieve google markers from google map object in angular google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-google-maps

[angular-google-maps](http://angular-google-maps.org/) abstracts the process of creating google markers (ie we don't do it directly via `new google.maps.Marker({...});`).. that said, there isn't a way for us to simply retrieve the markers pertaining to a google map object nor can we create our own array to store a reference to these markers for later usage (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6662514/766570))

Is there a way for us to retrieve the gMarkers pertaining to the google map object?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get to the raw code of google maps API v3 under AngularJS framework, I suggest you to use ngMap, https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps.

You can access the markers as $scope.markers as documented.

You can also access the map as $scope.map, shapes as $scope.shapes.

Here are the demos and documentation

[Demo](https://rawgithub.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/index.html)     
[Documentation](https://rawgithub.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/docs/index.html)

This directive does not watch markers and attributes. It only initialize the google map through the attributes given and let you handle all events with the raw Google maps API v3.

Btw, I created this directive.

Answer (score -1):

are you looking for this code?

You can access all markers data using loop..here is the sample

```
for(var i =0; i< allMarkers.length; i++)
{
  alert(allMarkers[i].getTitle());

  allMarkers[i].setMap(null);
}
```

Comment: Is this a serious answer?